# JBoss External Properties Files in Classpath

Tags: java, jboss

I was going through [JBoss.org](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath) how to put external file in the classpath, but it doesn't work.

I have 1 file with name "config.properties". It is placed in jboss/modules/com/xsiraul/test/main/ folder. In the same folder there is module.xml which looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.xsiraul.test">  
    <resources>  
        <resource-root path="."/>  
    </resources>  
</module>
```

I have load `config.properties` file from Java using -

```
InputStream settingsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

Java class is in package named com.xsiraul.test

The problem is that method `getResourceAsStream` returns NULL and I don't understand why. Maybe somebody has any ideas?

I use `JBoss` `EAP` 6.1.0.GA version.

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy your '*config.properties*' and '*module.xml*' in the following directory:

   ```
   <JBOSS-6.1-ROOT>/modules/system/layers/base/com/fico/test/main
   ```
2. Extend *'/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml'* by the following sub-system:

   ```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.1">
    <global-modules>
     <module name="com.fico.test" slot="main"/>
    </global-modules>
    <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
    <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
   </subsystem>
   ```
3. Restart JBoss

Comment: @ADTC I've just checked it again. It works perfectly well with JBoss 6+. Actually this was an answer to xsiraul. He has to do this additionally to changes he had already done (i.e. creation module directory and module.xml file). It will not work if you hasn't created these.

Comment: Put xml and properties in correct directory,  extended standalone.xml but didn't load the file. Do I have to change the WAR file as well as pointed out on the JBoss site? I am using JBoss 6.

Answer (score 2):

Did you declare the dependency to your module? maybe you missed that..

Add `Dependencies: com.fico.test` to your manifest.mf file

Comment: This was actually required in my case. JBoss 6.4