# Custom Deployment Folder in JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I'm working with Jboss 6.4, and I want to have this structure in my localhost deployment folder.

How is the way to change this in the config:

```
/usr/webapps/myApp/deployments/WAR

/usr/webapps/myApp/appconfig/myApp.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

In your standalone.xml, declare a relative dir

```
<system-properties>
     <property name="deploy.dir" value="/usr/webapps/myApp"/>
</system-properties>
```

. . . . . change the deploy-scanner path

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="deploy.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
 </subsystem>
```

To add external propreties file in the classpath  you can configure a nem module: [JBoss External Properties Files in Classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432321/jboss-external-properties-files-in-classpath)

Comment: The `relative-to` property is based on [path resources](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/General+configuration+concepts#Generalconfigurationconcepts-Paths) and not system properties.

Comment: @James R. Perkins ok then what is the correct way to do this change in the configuration?

Comment: You'd want to add a new `/path=deploy.dir:add(path=/usr/webapps/myApp)`.